# есть ли различия в подчёркиваниях? если да, то какие?

Tags: c++

в чём различие в __cdecl и _cdecl или __fastcall и _fastcall или __asm и _asm и т.д?

Comment: Да, есть. В первом случае подчеркивание на 1 символ больше, чем во втором) В остальном - это не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: Символы, начинающиеся с двух подчеркиваний зарезервированы для нужд имплементации, а начинающиеся с одного и строчной буквы - нет. Ну а смысл каждого надо прояснять в документации к каждому конкретному компилятору.

Comment: Для ассемблерных вставок в языке С++ существует ключевое слово `asm`. Никаких подчеркиваний в нем нет. Или ваш вопрос о неких абстрактных идентификаторах?